# Error converting data type varchar to bigint (C# ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to store a Int64 variable to data column with bigint data type. Following is my sql insert query and parameter declarations.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_subscribers VALUES ('@callerID2', '@timeStamp', '@unregisterDate ', '1')";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@callerID2", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        cmd.Parameters["@callerID2"].Value = SMSObject.callerID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@timeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters["@timeStamp"].Value = SMSObject.timeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@unregisterDate", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters["@unregisterDate"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

When it try to store the data, I get

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Any advices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
INSERT INTO tbl_subscribers VALUES ('@callerID2', ...
```

to

```
INSERT INTO tbl_subscribers VALUES (@callerID2, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of parametrized sql query, you don't need to put single quote (`'`) with parameter name.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_subscribers 
      VALUES (@callerID2, @timeStamp, @unregisterDate, '1')";
```